# Getting the headers in PHPExcel

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

I am using this piece of code in PHP to query a database and import the data to an excel file. Currently I am getting the data from the database, but I can't get the headers.

Can anyone tell me how to get the headers from the database?

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$col = 1; 
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = 1;
    foreach($row_data as $value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $row++;
    }
    $col++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$col = 1; 
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = 1;
    if ($col == 1) {
        $row_headings = array_keys($row_data);
        foreach($row_headings as $value) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
            $row++;
        }
        $row = 1;
        $col++;
    }
    foreach($row_data as $value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $row++;
    }
    $col++;
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to get the headers from the database. I still get the data without the headers.

Comment: Placed the $col=2 so that the data runs after the headers are in place.